# date issue with PHP 4.4.8

Tags: php, date, time, wordpress

Last week a released a 2.0 beta version of my Events Manager plugin, which produces a list of events. Among the many bugs floating around, there is one I cannot fix. The bug seems to manifest itself only on a tester's server with PHP 4.4.8; works allright on PHP 5.
When I try to use the `H:i` php time format, I always get midnight (00:00).
The issue is with the wordpress function mysql2date. This function is a wrapper around the date function.
I isolated the problem and inserted this in the website template:

```
echo (mysql2date("H:i", "0000-00-00 13:24:00"));
```

The result was

```
00:00
```

At first I thought it was a wordpress bug, but then I rewrote my function to employ `date()` straightaway. The result was even stranger, instead of midnight I got `11:59`.
Quite strangerly, both mysql2date and date seem to work allright on every other part of the plugin. Also, as I said, I cannot reproduce the bug on my server, only 2 users signalled it.

Since I was asked, here's the mysql2date code; it's part of Wordpress:

```
/**
 * Converts MySQL DATETIME field to user specified date format.
 *
 * If $dateformatstring has 'G' value, then gmmktime() function will be used to
 * make the time. If $dateformatstring is set to 'U', then mktime() function
 * will be used to make the time.
 *
 * The $translate will only be used, if it is set to true and it is by default
 * and if the $wp_locale object has the month and weekday set.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $dateformatstring Either 'G', 'U', or php date format.
 * @param string $mysqlstring Time from mysql DATETIME field.
 * @param bool $translate Optional. Default is true. Will switch format to locale.
 * @return string Date formated by $dateformatstring or locale (if available).
 */
function mysql2date( $dateformatstring, $mysqlstring, $translate = true ) {
    global $wp_locale;
    $m = $mysqlstring;
    if ( empty( $m ) )
        return false;

    if( 'G' == $dateformatstring ) {
        return gmmktime(
            (int) substr( $m, 11, 2 ), (int) substr( $m, 14, 2 ), (int) substr( $m, 17, 2 ),
            (int) substr( $m, 5, 2 ), (int) substr( $m, 8, 2 ), (int) substr( $m, 0, 4 )
        );
    }

    $i = mktime(
        (int) substr( $m, 11, 2 ), (int) substr( $m, 14, 2 ), (int) substr( $m, 17, 2 ),
        (int) substr( $m, 5, 2 ), (int) substr( $m, 8, 2 ), (int) substr( $m, 0, 4 )
    );

    if( 'U' == $dateformatstring )
        return $i;

    if ( -1 == $i || false == $i )
        $i = 0;

    if ( !empty( $wp_locale->month ) && !empty( $wp_locale->weekday ) && $translate ) {
        $datemonth = $wp_locale->get_month( date( 'm', $i ) );
        $datemonth_abbrev = $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev( $datemonth );
        $dateweekday = $wp_locale->get_weekday( date( 'w', $i ) );
        $dateweekday_abbrev = $wp_locale->get_weekday_abbrev( $dateweekday );
        $datemeridiem = $wp_locale->get_meridiem( date( 'a', $i ) );
        $datemeridiem_capital = $wp_locale->get_meridiem( date( 'A', $i ) );
        $dateformatstring = ' ' . $dateformatstring;
        $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])D/", "\\1" . backslashit( $dateweekday_abbrev ), $dateformatstring );
        $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])F/", "\\1" . backslashit( $datemonth ), $dateformatstring );
        $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])l/", "\\1" . backslashit( $dateweekday ), $dateformatstring );
        $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])M/", "\\1" . backslashit( $datemonth_abbrev ), $dateformatstring );
        $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])a/", "\\1" . backslashit( $datemeridiem ), $dateformatstring );
        $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])A/", "\\1" . backslashit( $datemeridiem_capital ), $dateformatstring );

        $dateformatstring = substr( $dateformatstring, 1, strlen( $dateformatstring ) -1 );
    }
    $j = @date( $dateformatstring, $i );

    /*
    if ( !$j ) // for debug purposes
        echo $i." ".$mysqlstring;
    */

    return $j;
}
```

If you're interested, you can download the code of my plugin [here](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/events-manager.zip), the problem is on line 613 of events-manager.php.

Can this have something to do with PHP or apache settings?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Davide

Comment: Can you post the code for mysql2date or your replacement?

Comment: I don't think it's an apache/mysql issue.  I would suggest that you add a line in there to log the issue whenever it arises; check if mysql2date(...) == 00:00 (and the system time != 00:00).  Log all relevant variables. I'd first check to see what the argument values are before proceeding.

Comment: Actually the weird thing is the values are allright; as a temporary patch I added a simple substr() call to parse the time, so the source variable are prefectly allright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have solved this issue. The problem was `0000-00-00`, apparently not a valid time mysql2date value in some PHP/MySql combos (quite understandably, I am looking at you, month `00`...) . I ended up using `echo (mysql2date("H:i", "2000-10-10 13:24:00"));`

Since I am just interested in the hours and minute a more casual date does the job. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix, but an alternative - use UNIX_TIMESTAMP in your mysql statement instead of converting it afterwards.

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_created`) AS `date`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually ended up implementing another workaround, but this is alsoa  good idea.